# Son of Suckerfish Menu IE6 - menu hiding behind content

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, suckerfish

Page - http://blu-eye.com/index.html - contains suckerfish menu which is displaying correctly on the rest of the site, except for this page. The menu items are hidden behind the content below.

The content below it contains a javascript slider with image and text. I've tried changing the z-indexes on majority of elements, but still having no luck.

It only occurs in IE (6 and 7).

Please help!

Comment: z-index should help, which elements/how do you set them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drama you have is the use of relative positioned elements, which reset the z-order context on < IE8.

Specifically on div#header, remove the position relative. then on div#cat_528463_divs > ul > li set a z-index (of 1000 for eg). This will fix the nav issue from tucking in under the JS slider – however it will screw up the look of the rest of the top section, because they are absolutely positioning the logo and some other images. So that is going to need to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

IE has a slightly different stacking order of elements so just setting something with a different z-index will not necessarily move it above.

Taking your starting point as your wrapper, add position:relative to it and then work down into your HTML. If you imagine that at your start point, then you need to get your menu div and your slider div to at least the same 'depth'.

You might find adding position:relative to #content as well might help.

You can then change the z-indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index:100` to the submenu's li's

```
#nav_528463 li ul li {
  -moz-background-clip:border;
  -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
  -moz-background-origin:padding;
  background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this bit of jQuery very handy for your problem:

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/